# Multivariable chain rule problem with second partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I've recently learned the chain rule for multivariable calculus, and received the following question on our latest assignment:

$w:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a twice differentiable function such that $\triangle w=w_{xx}+w_{yy}=0$

Define:
$$\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2},\quad \phi(u,v)=(u^2-v^2,2uv)$$

Let $h$ be the composition of $w$ and $\phi$:
$$h:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\quad h=w\circ\phi$$ Prove $\triangle h=h_{uu}+h_{vv}=0$

This is what I have done so far:

Define:
$$x(u,v)=u^2-v^2,\quad y(u,v)=2uv$$
So, using the chain rule, we will find the first partial derivative of $h$ with respect to $u$:
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=2u\cdot\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}+2v\cdot\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}$$

And the second partial derivative with respect to $u$ will be:
$$\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial^2 u}=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(2u\cdot\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}+2v\cdot\frac{\partial h}{\partial y})$$

I do the same thing with the partial derivatives of $h$ with respect to $v$, and I get:
$$\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial^2 v}=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}(-2v\cdot\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}+2u\cdot\frac{\partial h}{\partial y})$$

Here I am stuck. I am not sure what I can do with the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: What is $w \circ \phi$?

Comment: It's a function composition, I'll edit the post for clarity

Comment: Okay, I asked because you originally  wrote that the range of $\phi$ is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yep, I've edited that too, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure what I can do with the partial derivatives $\tfrac{∂h}{∂y}$ and $\tfrac{∂h}{∂x}$.

Leave them, as they are cleaner to write.

They are actually the compositions: $\tfrac{\partial h}{\partial x}=\tfrac{\partial \omega}{\partial x}\circ\phi$ and $\tfrac{\partial h}{\partial y}=\tfrac{\partial \omega}{\partial y}\circ\phi$ .

Therefore $\tfrac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x~^2}+\tfrac{\partial^2 h}{\partial y~^2}=0$, because $\left[\tfrac{\partial^2 \omega}{\partial x~^2}+\tfrac{\partial^2 \omega}{\partial y~^2}\right]\circ\phi=0$.

So your aim is just to show that when evaluating $\tfrac{\partial^2 h}{\partial u~^2}+\tfrac{\partial^2 h}{\partial v~^2}$, you have a product of some factor and the sum $\tfrac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x~^2}+\tfrac{\partial^2 h}{\partial y~^2}$, and all other terms vanish.

---

Up next is the product rule:$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial^2 h}{\partial u^2}&=\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial u}\left(2u\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x}+2v\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial y}\right)\\&=2\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x}+2u\left(\dfrac{\partial ~~}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right)+0+2v\left(\dfrac{\partial ~~}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial y}\right)\end{align}$$

... and then the chain rule again.  Likewise for the double v derivative.  Finally, add and see what cancels.

Comment: Personally I would have stuck with the $h_u$ and $h_x:=\omega_x{\circ}\phi$ notation.$$\begin{align}h_u&=2 u~h_x+2v~h_y\\h_{uu}& = 2~h_x+2u~(h_x)_u+2v~(h_y)_u\end{align}$$

Comment: This was very clear, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Denote by
$\mathbf{J}=2\begin{pmatrix} u & -v \\ v & u \end{pmatrix}$ the Jacobian matrix so that $d\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{J}\cdot d\mathbf{u}$.

It is easy to see that gradients in both coordinates are linked by the relation
$\mathbf{g}_u = \mathbf{J}^T \mathbf{g}_x$.

Differentiating this expression, yields
\begin{eqnarray}
d\mathbf{g}_u 
&=& 
(d\mathbf{J})^T \mathbf{g}_x + \mathbf{J}^T d\mathbf{g}_x 
=
\left[
\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{J}^T \mathbf{H}_x \mathbf{J} 
\right]
d\mathbf{u}  \\
\end{eqnarray}
Note: I leave to you to compute the $\mathbf{A}$ matrix.

The bracket term is the Hessian in $(u,v)$ coordinates. Doing computations, you will see that the trace of the bracket term is indeed null if $\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{H}_x)=0$.